# Is there a mathematical concept for permutations of items where any number can be picked but must be in order?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm looking for a mathematical concept where I have a list of things in order, and I want to combine them by picking all the possible orders where I pick them in order.

For example, with two items, I can pick only the first or only the second or the first followed by the second (but not the second followed by the first).

```
a
b
ab
```

For three items:

```
a
b
c
ab
ac
bc
abc
```

I'm working on this for just enjoyment. The only thing I've discovered so far is that the number of possibilities is always $2^n - 1$ where $n$ is the number of items. And it seems that calculating the various possibilities might be recursive.

Comment: Surely the total count is $2^n-1$, not $n^2-1$.  What you've described is just the collection of non-empty subsets of the given set.

Comment: You're right, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically equivalent to the powerset of a set (excluding the empty set). You can also think of it using binary numbers.  For example if you have "abcd" then you have $1000 \mapsto a$, $1010 \mapsto ac$.
From this you can see that the number of these selections would be $2^n -1$ as lulu pointed out in the comments.